# angular ui-bootstrap pagination not working with url with back or forward button

Tags: angularjs, url, pagination, angular-bootstrap

I am using ui-bootstrap pagination, getting the data from server based on the page clicked. every time it will send the request to server like this. 'apiURL?skip='+0 ,If i click on back button, it will update the url, not the view and also  the page number will stay active in previous page. and also i want to be worked when i directly place the url in browser with some page number.can anyone please help me how to do with page url.

```
mainEvents: function() {
    var self = this;
    var currentItem =0;
    return $http.get(UrlService.baseUrl + '/event/upcoming?skip='+ currentItem ).then(function(response) {
        var events = response.data.events;
        var eventsLen = events.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < eventsLen; i++) {
            self.prepareForRendering(events[i]);
        }
        var totalItems = response.data.events.length;
        angular.copy(response.data.events, upEvents);
        return events;
    }, function(response) {
        return $q.reject(response.data.error)
    });
},
$scope.pageChanged = function() {
   mainEvents(currentItem);
   var currentItem = ($scope.currentNumber - 1) * 10;
   $location.search('page', $scope.currentNumber);  //$scope.currentNumber is pageNumber
};
```

**html**

```
 <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentNumber" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
```